# How to use Quarkus to read data from Redis Stream?

Tags: java, redis, quarkus

Am trying to read data from Redis stream using Quarkus. But am unable to achieve it.Upon checking the Quarkus guide,stream is not available yet .Is there any other way that I could read data from Redis Stream using Quarkus

Using Redis API

```
 @Startup
  void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("Stream");
    Redis.createClient(vertx)
        .connect()
        .onSuccess(connection -> {
          // use the connection
          System.out.println("Successfully connected = " + connection + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          connection.handler(message -> {
            // do whatever you need to do with your message
            System.out.println("Message = " + message + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          });
          connection.send(Request.cmd(Command.XRANGE).arg("test").arg("-").arg("+"))
              .onSuccess(res -> {
                System.out.println("Subscribed");
                System.out.println(res);
              });
        });
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE], otherwise it might be difficult to help.

Comment: The high-level (datasource) API does not provide Redis Streams command yet, but you can use the low level APIs (`Redis` and `RedisAPI`) and use the commands directly.

Comment: Using low level APIs am able to read data from stream, I want to a listener to recv seq of data. is there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

I make it work using `Multi.createBy().repeating()`:

```
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class StreamListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamListener.class);

    private static final String CHANNEL = "channel";
    private static final String STREAM = "stream";
    private static final String STREAM_GROUP = "stream_0";
    private static final String STREAM_CONSUMER = "consumer";

    private final ReactiveStreamCommands<String, String, MyMessage> stream;
    private Cancellable consumer;

    public StreamListener(ReactiveRedisDataSource ds) {
        this.stream = ds.stream(MyMessage.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void onStart() {
        log.info("Stream listener is starting...");

        this.consumer = this.stream.xgroupCreate(STREAM, STREAM_GROUP, "0-0")
                .onFailure().recoverWithNull()
                .map(v -> this.stream.xgroupCreateConsumer(STREAM, STREAM_GROUP, STREAM_CONSUMER))
                .map(v -> createStreamListener())
                .subscribe().with(cancellable -> this.consumer = cancellable);

        log.info("Subscribed to {} channel", CHANNEL);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void onStop() {
        log.info("The application is stopping...");
        this.consumer.cancel();
        this.stream.xgroupDelConsumer(STREAM, STREAM_GROUP, STREAM_CONSUMER)
                .subscribe()
                .with(unack -> log.info("Consumer deleted with {} unacknowledged messages", unack));
    }

    private Cancellable createStreamListener() {
        log.info("Creating stream listener");
        XReadGroupArgs args = new XReadGroupArgs().block(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).count(10);
        return Multi.createBy()
                .repeating()
                .uni(() -> this.stream.xreadgroup(STREAM_GROUP, STREAM_CONSUMER, STREAM, ">", args)
                        .onFailure().recoverWithItem(emptyList()))
                .indefinitely()
                .map(this::processMessage)
                .onFailure().recoverWithItem(e -> {
                    log.error("Cannot process message", e);
                    return new String[0];
                })
                .map(this::acknowledge)
                .onItem().transformToUniAndConcatenate(Function.identity())
                .subscribe()
                .with(count -> log.debug("Collected {} requests", count));
    }

    String[] processMessage(List<StreamMessage<String, String, MyMessage>> messages) {
        List<String> messageIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (StreamMessage<String, String, MyMessage> message : messages) {
            messageIds.add(message.id());
            // do your job here
        }
        return messageIds.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    Uni<Integer> acknowledge(String[] ids) {
        log.debug("Acknowledge {} messages", ids.length);
        return ids.length > 0 ? this.stream.xack(STREAM, STREAM_GROUP, ids) : Uni.createFrom().item(0);
    }

    @Scheduled(every = "1h")
    void trimStream() {
        this.stream.xtrim(STREAM, new XTrimArgs().maxlen(10000).nearlyExactTrimming())
                .subscribe().with(count -> log.info("Trimmed {} messages from stream {}", count, STREAM));
    }

    private static class MyMessage {
    }
}
```